# Secondary domains not working on dedicated server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, domain-name-system, virtualhost

I have a domain pointing to the dedicated IP address on my dedicated server working fine.

The problem is that any other domains I create pointing to shared IP addresses on the server are not working. I changed the vhosts in the `htttp.d/conf` file to point directly to the dedicated IP address and have the path to the new domain (e.g `/home/domain/domain.com/html`) or even pointing to the shared IP address (e.g `192.168.1.2`) with no luck.

I changed the A records from the dedicated to the shared IP address and back with no luck.

I feel like I tried everything so far but I may be mistaken since I'm not a Server admin but a web dev.

Note: I'm using Interworx.

Note2: I'm using my own nameservers. (e.g. `ns1.myownservers.com` / `ns2.myownservers.com` )

Comment: Exactly what did you set up? Your question isn't at all clear.

Answer (score 1):

- Check that your network cards are configured to use the IP addresses you are using.
- Check that your firewall (probably IPtables) is configured to allow traffic to those IP addresses.
- Check that your web server is listening on those IP addresses.
- Set vhosts to listen on all addresses using the wildcard.
- Setup your vhosts to use your domain names and FQDN names - in apache use ServerName for one of them and ServerAlias for any additional ones.
- Make sure that DNS is configured to point your domain names/FQDNs at your IP addresses using A records or via CNAMES that in turn point to A records.

Optional - figure out the basics of web hosting before you start on your own nameservers.  You are trying to learn too much too fast.  Keep the moving parts to a minimum.